# Django (Gunicorn) doesn't see ENV VARS in production but Django-shell does

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, environment-variables, gunicorn

I'm pretty desperate here. I can't figure out why `Django` doesn't see environment variables even if `shell` can.

in **settings.py**

```
BASE_URL = os.getenv('VUE_APP_WEB_URL','http://127.0.0.1:8080/')
```

in **admin.py**

```
class _UserAdmin...
    ...
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'is_staff', '_set_pwd_url','base_url')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'groups')

    def base_url(self, obj: User):
        return settings.BASE_URL
```

in **/etc/environment**

```
VUE_APP_WEB_URL=http://my.url.xyz/
```

Server has been rebooted multiple times, also `Gunicorn` has been restarted by `sudo service gunicorn restart`

[image]

It's still showing the default value, not the ENV VAR.

Now, when I test it in `django shell`:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> settings.BASE_URL
'http://my.url.xyz/'
>>>
```

What is going on?

PS: Browser cache is not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried storing your `envs` in a file and point gunicorn to that file?

Answer (score 2):

Make a `.env` file in your (preferably root) directory and then configure your `gunicorn.service` configuration to point to that file.

make a `.env` file

```
VUE_APP_WEB_URL= 'http://my.url.xyz/'
ANOTHER_VARIABLE = 'something'
```

then add `EnvironmentFile` to your configuration

```
...

[Service]  
...
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/your/.env
ExecStart=
...
```

You can also use `pip install django-dotenv` which will also look for .env and initialise it.